# materialize Dropdwon in Angular js after ajax call

Tags: angularjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc, materialize

I have a master page and child page in MVC

All Js files are included in master page.Now in child page I have two dropdowns which gets bind with ajax returned data.

I can see data are being populated in select options but materialize css not created.

**HTML**

```
<select data-ng-init="getAllItems()"  ng-model="Item[0]" ng-options="Item['title'] for Item in Items track by Item['id']">
```

**AJAX**

```
$scope.getAllItems = function () {
        var result = ItemsFactory();
        result.then(function (result) {

            if (result.success) {
                $scope.Items= (result.data);
            }
        });
    }
```

I have used

```
$('select').material_select()
```

in a js file that is included on master page at the end,

So my thinking is the JS where I am using **$('select').material_select()** gets loaded before dropdown populations, but I have included it at the end,

**I Manage to get it worked**

```
 $scope.getAllItems = function () {
                var result = ItemsFactory();
                result.then(function (result) {

                    if (result.success) {
                        $scope.Items= (result.data);
                        $('select').material_select()
                    }
                });
            }

  $scope.$apply($scope.getAllItems ());
```

but on console I am getting error 
**[$rootScope:inprog]**

any suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code where you populating data

Comment: I have updated. though data is being populated correctly

Answer (score 0):

So, you have two ways:

1) It is put your select initialization in `then` fuction. *Not the good way*

```
  $scope.getAllItems = function () {
    var result = ItemsFactory();
    result.then(function (result) {

        if (result.success) {
            $scope.Items= (result.data);

            $('select').material_select();

            $scope.$apply();
        }
    });
}
```

2) Make a directive that wraps `.material_select()`. *Better way*

```
    .directive('materialSelect', [function(){

       return {
           restrict: 'E',
           scope: {
               items: '='
           },
           link: function(scope, elem attrs) {

              elem.material_select()

           }

       }

    }])

  <material-select items="items"></material-select>
```

**UPDATE**

```
 $scope.getAllItems = function () {
            var result = ItemsFactory();
            result.then(function (result) {

                if (result.success) {
                    $scope.Items= (result.data);
                    $('select').material_select()

                    $scope.$apply()
                }
            });
        }

  $scope.getAllItems ();
```

Comment: I have a js file say common.js in which with other code I have written $('select').material_select() and included that js on master page

Comment: It is working on page where I have populated item on index action returning model, this is the second dropdown page which takes data from ajax call

Comment: It looks like before ajax gets completed , the custom.js file loaded, however I have write "$('select').material_select()" inside document.ready

Comment: Don't you forget about `$scope.$apply()`?, if is it not helping, try second way

Comment: I have given that one, what is <material-select items="items"></material-select>

Comment: I have to bind data in plain <select> tag, materialize.js automatically create another ui li set from this

Comment: Look at this solution https://github.com/krescruz/angular-materialize/, also here you can find https://github.com/krescruz/angular-materialize/blob/master/src/angular-materialize.js how can you implement select in angular. Search in file for `materialSelect`

Comment: I have just started angular.js so those pages bouncing to me, however when i tried " $scope.$apply($scope.getAllItems ());" it acutally worked, but on console it shows Error: "[$rootScope:inprog]"

Comment: I see, can you update the question with your new code?

Comment: One problem I am facing, when I select the item from list, in actual dropdown list first item replaced with selected item, where as li created by materialize.js is fine